# How to stop a calculation in GAP without closing GAP?

Tags: group-theory, gap

I have the following question concerning GAP:

> If I want to stop a calculation, how can I do this?

I know the command Ctrl+Z, but then GAP is closed.

I am using Linux Ubuntu 14.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This comment is slightly off topic but ctrl + z doesn't close a program in *nix is makes it a background process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CTRL-C will interrupt a calculation (and enter the break loop -- type quit; or press CTRL-D to exit it).
Note that some calculations purely within the kernel (e.g. matrix inversion) cannot be interrupted.

Comment: And the link for the appropriate section in the GAP manual is [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap6.html#X8593B49F8705B486)